# jQuery various field addition with optional checkboxes w/ JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am summing everything for a total on my page with the following: http://jsfiddle.net/7wWR6/

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.newreservation').click(function() {
                //get the numbers
                var rent = parseFloat($('.rentalcharges').find('#rent').val());
                var cleaning = parseFloat($('.rentalcharges').find('#cleaning').val());
                var booking = parseFloat($('.rentalcharges').find('#booking').val());
                var taxes = parseFloat($('.rentalcharges').find('#taxes').val());
                var total = 0;
                total = total + (rent+cleaning+booking+taxes);
                //set the total
                 $('.rentalcharges').find('#total').val(total);
                 console.log('total: ' + total);
            });
            $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){

              //get the numbers
                    var rent = parseFloat($('.rentalcharges').find('#rent').val());
                    var cleaning = parseFloat($('.rentalcharges').find('#cleaning').val());
                    var booking = parseFloat($('.rentalcharges').find('#booking').val());
                    var taxes = parseFloat($('.rentalcharges').find('#taxes').val());
                    var total = 0;
                    total = total + (rent+cleaning+booking+taxes);
                    var checked;
                     if($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')){
                        checked = parseFloat($('input[type=checkbox]').val());
                         total = total + checked;
                     }else{
                         total = total - checked;
                     }
                //set the total
             $('.rentalcharges').find('#total').val(total);
                 });
        });
    </script>
```

It all works except for the checkboxes. They do nothing but log a total of 0. How can I fix this? I'll try to make a jsfiddle if need be. I just am using a lot of mySQL for the fields and obviously can't simply copy/paste.

EDIT: I made a barebones fiddle that i think represents my situation: http://jsfiddle.net/7wWR6/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a click event try a change event like this.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change();
```

Also it looks like u don't need the .find() when your selecting elements.

Instead of this

```
$('.rentalcharges').find('#cleaning').val()
```

You can do this

```
$('#cleaning').val();
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/5k6aX/1/ The checkbox value needed to be added to the total calculation in the click event of the other inputs.